# My picture is not saved into my uploads/pictures folder

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

**My Controller Codes**

Looking forward for your help! thank you :

```
public function index()
{
    $registration = $this->Registration_model->get_all();

    $data = array(
        'registration_data' => $registration
    );

    $this->load->view('registration/registration_list', $data);

}
 public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/pictures/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000000;
            $config['max_width']            = 10240000;
            $config['max_height']           = 76800000;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('Image'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('registration_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    return $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            }
    }
public function read($id) 
{
    $row = $this->Registration_model->get_by_id($id);
    if ($row) {
        $data = array(
    'id' => $row->id,
    'firstName' => $row->firstName,
    'lastName' => $row->lastName,
    'gender' => $row->gender,
    'address' => $row->address,
    'dob' => $row->dob,
    'Image' => $row->Image,
    );
        $this->load->view('registration/registration_read', $data);
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
        redirect(site_url('registration'));
    }
}

public function create() 
{
    $data = array(
        'button' => 'Create',
        'action' => site_url('registration/create_action'),
    'id' => set_value('id'),
    'firstName' => set_value('firstName'),
    'lastName' => set_value('lastName'),
    'gender' => set_value('gender'),
    'address' => set_value('address'),
    'dob' => set_value('dob'),
    'Image' =>set_value('image'),
);
    $this->load->view('registration/registration_form', $data);
        }

public function create_action() 
{
    $this->_rules();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->create();
    } else {
        $data = array(
    'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName',TRUE),
    'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName',TRUE),
    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender',TRUE),
    'address' => $this->input->post('address',TRUE),
    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob',TRUE),
    'Image' => $this->input->post('Image',TRUE),
    );

        $this->Registration_model->insert($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'The New Record was Successfuly Added');
        redirect(site_url('registration'));
    }
}
```

**My Views Codes**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Dob <?php echo form_error('dob') ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="Dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="varchar">Image <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?></label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="Image" id="Image" height="50" />
    <br/>
 </div>
  <br/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"name="userSubmit"><?php echo $button ?></button>
```

**My Model**

```
class Registration_model extends CI_Model
{

    public $table = 'registration';
    public $id = 'id';
    public $order = 'DESC';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // get all
    function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }

    // get data by id
    function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
    }

    // get total rows
    function total_rows($q = NULL) {
        $this->db->like('id', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('firstName', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('lastName', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('gender', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('address', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('dob', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('Image', $q);
    $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    // get data with limit and search
    function get_limit_data($limit, $start = 0, $q = NULL) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        $this->db->like('id', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('firstName', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('lastName', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('gender', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('address', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('dob', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('Image', $q);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }

    // insert data
    function insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }

    // update data
    function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    // delete data
    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

}
```

Comment: check the correct path first and than folder permission

Comment: check first path `$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/pictures/';`

Comment: you need to debug your code and find errors you are getting based on code it's not possible to identify the problem

Comment: @nicolas I already check it but it still won't work..

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can try this

```
 $config['upload_path'] = 'ADD HERE YOUR SITE PATH TO PICTURE'; // Like SITE_PATH .'/uploads/pictures/';
```

and print $config['upload_path'] and check it's correct your upload picture path

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before. Depending on your server, you may want to remove the ./ from your upload path.

```
public function do_upload()
{
  $config['upload_path']  = 'uploads/pictures/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view as below. You are not closing form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="date">Dob <?php echo form_error('dob') ?></label>
    input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="Dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="varchar">Image </label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="Image" id="Image" height="50" />
<br/>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"name="userSubmit"><?php echo $button ?></button>
<?= form_close()?>
```